# CodeIgniter 3.x deprecated functions in PHP 5.3.29

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm running Apache v2.2 with PHP v5.3.29, with CodeIgniter v3.0 which list some functions as deprecated.

Anyone have an information what version CI for PHP 5.3.29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter 3. is not working on php 5.3. Update it to 5.4+ or use Codeigniter 2.0 version.

> **PHP version 5.4 or newer is recommended.**

To [CI 2 Download](https://www.codeigniter.com/download)

**Server Requirements**

> It should work on **5.2.4** as well, but we strongly advise you NOT to run such old versions of PHP, because of potential security and performance issues, as well as missing features.

A database is required for most web application programming. Currently supported databases are:

1. MySQL (5.1+) via the mysql (deprecated), mysqli and pdo drivers
2. Oracle via the oci8 and pdo drivers
3. PostgreSQL via the postgre and pdo drivers
4. MS SQL via the mssql, sqlsrv (version 2005 and above only) and pdo
   drivers
5. SQLite via the sqlite (version 2), sqlite3 (version 3) and
       pdo drivers CUBRID via the cubrid and pdo drivers
6. Interbase/Firebird via the ibase and pdo drivers
7. ODBC via the odbc and pdo drivers (you should know that ODBC is
   actually an abstraction layer)

[CI 3 Server Requirements](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html)

---

**CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.2.0**

**Server Requirements**

> PHP version **5.1.6** or newer.
>
> A Database is required for most web application programming. Current supported databases are MySQL (4.1+), MySQLi, MS SQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQLite, and ODBC

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 2 version works for php 5.1.x and upwards, download here: https://www.codeigniter.com/download